# Postgres import csv duplicate keys

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, duplicate-data

I have a table called measurement with 3 columns: value, moment, seriesid.

```
51.02|2006-12-31 23:00:00|1
24.88|2006-12-31 23:00:00|2
55|2006-12-31 23:00:00|3
3.34823004011|2006-12-31 23:00:00|5
```

I am trying to load a csv in this table and I am getting the following error:

```
Key (moment, seriesid)=(2009-05-25 00:00:00,186) already exists.
```

After reading some posts here on StackOverflow, best I managed to do was this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE measurement_tmp AS SELECT * FROM measurement LIMIT 0;
COPY measurement_tmp FROM '/home/airquality/dat/import.csv'
WITH DELIMITER ',';

INSERT INTO measurement
SELECT DISTINCT ON (moment,seriesid)
value,moment,seriesid
FROM measurement_tmp
```

As far as I understand 
1) A table measurement_tmp is created. 
2) All contents of the measurement table are loaded in measeurement_tmp 
3) All contents of the import.csv file are loaded in measurement_tmp without Key (moment, seriesid) restriction. 
4) Selecting DISTINCT ON (moment, seriesid) should only return only 'sane' data and import them in measurement.

Still getting the same error,

```
2014-11-20 10:06:24 GMT-2 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
 "measurement_pkey"
2014-11-20 10:06:24 GMT-2 DETAIL:  Key (moment, seriesid)=(2009-05-25 00:00:00,
186) already exists.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the measurement table is not empty, and the new rows collide with the existing ones?

Comment: Oh my god you are so right. I am going to backup the existing db and create a normal table for the job, empty the old and try again. At the moment I split up the csv in 10 smaller ones and I have 10 threads updating the database one query for each line. Most annoying update I've done in my life. And when if I write a proper UPSERT postgres function I will post it here. I tried a few I found on the net but I couldn't manage to make them work for me.

Comment: No need for a function. Just do the UPDATE ...  ; followed by `INSERT INTO target table() SELECT ... FROM source_table s WHERE NOT EXISTS(select * from targettable x WHERE x.keyfields = s.keyfields);`